# fullcalendar Invalid date on safari

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

i have project in php everything is working fine on google chrome. but, it does not working on safari or mac. showing an error:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
>   _WidgetJPCB2.js:-1Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
>   _PCcb:-1Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
>   _PCcb:-1Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.

here is my code

```
<div class="calenderarea"style="zoom:75%!important;" >
<div class="calendarsection" ></div>
<!------ 
style="-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; background:linear-gradient(rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.52), rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.09)), url('images/booking1.jpg');
background-size:160vh 100%;background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center center;"
------------>
     </div>
```

here is my script

```
<script>
    function check_sv_pas_seats() {
        var pro_id = $('#trip_id').val();
        $('#sv_pas_seats').empty();
        $('#check_my_sv_1').empty();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check.php',
                data: 'my_sv_program_id_4_seats=' + pro_id,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data >= 6) {

                        for (i = 1; i <= data; i++) {
                            $('#sv_pas_seats').append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
                        }
                        $('#check_my_sv_1').empty();
                        $("#check_my_sv_1").val(data);
                    } else if (data == 0) {
                        alert("No seats 
                            available
                            for this date ");
                        }
                        else if (data <= 5) {
                            for (i = 1; i <= data; i++) {
                                $('#sv_pas_seats').append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
                            }
                            $('#check_my_sv_1').empty();
                            // document.getElementById('check_my_sv_1').value = data;
                            $("#check_my_sv_1").val(data);

                        } else if (data == 000000) {
                            alert('Error!!! please try again. Type - 1');
                        } else {
                            alert('Error!!! please try again.');
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        function myfunc() {
            var sval_1 = $("#sv_pas_seats").val();
            var sval_2 = $("#check_my_sv_1").val();
            var sum = sval_2 - sval_1;
            $('#ch_seats').empty();
            for (i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
                $('#ch_seats').append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
            }
        }

        function mychild3() {
            $('#s_ncs3').show();
        }

        function mychild4() {
            $('#s_ncs3').hide();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: why have you set `dataType: 'jsonp'` if it's not a JSONP request. This is almost certainly the source of your message. a JSONP request would be expected to return some script. Possibly other browsers are tolerant of your mistake, but not Safari. Try `dataType: 'json'` instead, if your ajax request is returning JSON data.

Comment: i also try to change jsonp to json still getting error same

Comment: what exactly is the content of the `data` variable when it arrives in your response?

Comment: look at this site
http://seatoursdubai.cf/user/booking.php
open in chrome and safari
chrome will work fine but in safari give me Invalid Date

Comment: that wasn't what I asked. And I haven't got a Mac so can't test in Safari. And relevant info should be within the question here, please, not on some random link

Answer (score 0):

i found the Error 
actually in safari time variable become invalid that's why got error
and now i fixed it